# Is there any way to make VIM fold one line more?

Tags: vim, folding

I am using an adaptation of the VIM folding settings published [here](http://dhruvasagar.com/2013/03/28/vim-better-foldtext) and [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html). Now, notice the program below:

[image: a]

When folded on my VIM, it produces the following result:

[image: b]

I don't really like that look, I'd prefer the following:

[image: c]

Which I got by rewriting the code:

[image: d]

But leaving the code like that is horrible. Is it possible to update the VimScript so I get the folding I want, without having to leave the JavaScript code like that?

Here is my exact setting:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=GetPotionFold(v:lnum)
setlocal foldminlines=0

function! s:NextNonBlankLine(lnum)
    let numlines = line('$')
    let current = a:lnum + 1

    while current <= numlines
        if getline(current) =~? '\v\S'
            return current
        endif

        let current += 1
    endwhile

    return -2
endfunction

function! s:IndentLevel(lnum)
    return indent(a:lnum) / &shiftwidth
endfunction

function! GetPotionFold(lnum)
    if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
        return '-1'
    endif

    let this_indent = <SID>IndentLevel(a:lnum)
    let next_indent = <SID>IndentLevel(<SID>NextNonBlankLine(a:lnum))

    if next_indent == this_indent
        return this_indent
    elseif next_indent < this_indent
        return this_indent
    elseif next_indent > this_indent
        return '>' . next_indent
    endif
endfunction

function! NeatFoldText()
  let line = getline(v:foldstart)
  let lines_count = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
  let lines_count_text = '| ' . printf("%10s", lines_count . ' lines') . ' |'
  let foldchar = ' '
  let foldtextstart = strpart(line, 0, (winwidth(0)*2)/3)
  let foldtextend = lines_count_text . repeat(foldchar, 6)
  let foldtextlength = strlen(substitute(foldtextstart . foldtextend, '.', 'x', 'g')) + &foldcolumn
  return foldtextstart . repeat(foldchar, winwidth(0)-foldtextlength) . foldtextend
endfunction
set foldtext=NeatFoldText()

hi Folded ctermbg=255 ctermfg=21
hi FoldColumn ctermbg=white ctermfg=darkred
```

And here is the sample code:

```
function foo(x){
    var y = x*x;
    var z = y+y;
    return z;
};

function bar(x){
    var y = x*x;
    var z = y+y;
    return z;
};

function foobar(x){
    var y = x*x;
    var z = y+y;
    return z;
};

function barfoo(x){
    var y = x*x;
    var z = y+y;
    return z;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker={,}
```

Should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fold expression that is (as far as I can see from a glance) designed for indent folding (used for HAML, Python, Haskell and other indent-syntax languages).

For C, you should just be using `:set foldmethod=syntax`.

Comment: Weird, `:set foldmethod=syntax` seems to make folding stop working for the JS code presented here.

Comment: Ah, right, I wasn't paying attention. JavaScript does not have good syntax definitions. You can use [JavaScript Syntax plugin](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax) to solve that.